# How do I import tables from another database in sqlite using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

How do I import data from a column in another table in another database into the current database's table's column?

I tried using the "ATTACH" command, but I'm only allowed to execute one statement at a time.

```
 cursor.execute(
        "ATTACH DATABASE other.db AS other;\
        INSERT INTO table \
        (column1) \
        SELECT column1\
        FROM other.table;")
```

Comment: What is wrong with `SELECT` from one database and then `INSERT` into another?

Comment: Then why don't you execute the two statements one at a time?

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't work. I'll try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to call `execute` twice, and enclose `other.db` is single quotations

```
 cursor.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;")
 cursor.execute("\
        INSERT INTO table \
        (ID) \
        SELECT ID \
        FROM other.table ;")
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of `execute` you may want to do an `executescript`. Like so...

```
cursor.executescript("""ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;
                        INSERT INTO table (column1)
                        SELECT column1
                        FROM other.table;""")
```

(assuming other.db is an sqlite file)